# onclick function not working after extra append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, append

I've walked into an irritating problem which i can't find a solution for.
Hopefully you can help me with this. All help is welcome.

### Situation

I've created an slider for the website i'm working on. To toggle between tabs manually, i've added some clickable div's via javascript which brings the corresponding tab to the front. Now i've added an option to pause/play the slider, so it won't go any further in cycling through the tabs when on pause.

### Code

```
for ( i = 0; i < imageTextTemp.length; i++)
{
    var temp = [];
    marginLeftValue = i * 23 + 10;
    $(tabs).append( "<div class='subdiv_" + i + "' id='subDiv' style='margin-left: " + marginLeftValue + "px; margin-top: -40px;' onclick='setImageSlider(" + i + ")'></div>");
    temp.push(imageTextTemp[i].getElementsByTagName("location_big")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    temp.push(imageTextTemp[i].getElementsByTagName("location_small")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    temp.push(imageTextTemp[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    temp.push(imageTextTemp[i].getElementsByTagName("column")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    imageText.push(temp);
}
marginLeftValue = marginLeftValue + 46;
$(tabs).append( "<div class='pauseplaySlider' id='pauseplay' style='margin-left: " + marginLeftValue + "px; margin-top: -40px;'></div>");
```

Later in the process, the following is happening:

```
document.getElementById('pauseplay').setAttribute("onclick", "pauseSlider();");
$('#pauseplay').css('background-image', 'url("' + siteUrl + 'includes/images/pause.png")');
```

### Explanation

`imageTextTemp` is an array of banner images. `tabs` is the div in which the buttons must be shown. The `temp` array is not very interesting for this case, but because it is in between the two interesting codes, i've left it there.

### Problem

Now the weird part: As soon as i added the last append, outside the for loop, the onclick functions of the appends inside the for loop stopped working.

### Effect

Before adding the last `pauseplaySlider` the `tabs` divs did there job as should do. They brought you to the corresponding slider directly without waiting for it. After adding the last `pauseplaySlider` the `tabs` divs stopped working, but the pause/play button just worked fine, without any problems. They should be working both.

### Question

Why won't the work both at the same time?

### Tried

- I've already tried to change the onclick within the for loop to `alert(" + i + ");` which didn't work either.
- After commenting the append outside the for loop, the div's within the for loop started working again.
- After changing the onclick of the `pauseplay` div to `alert(1);` nothing really changed. The `pauseplay` gave an alert with the value 1, and the div's within the for still didn't work.

### Edit

I've changed the following after multiple reactions on this question:

- I've change the `document.getElementById('pauseplay').setAttribute("onclick", "pauseSlider();");` to `$('#pauseplay').on("click",function () { pauseSlider(); });`
- I've changed the append in the for loop to:

  ```
  $(tabs).append( "<div class='subdiv_" + i + "' id='subDiv' style='margin-left: " + marginLeftValue + "px; margin-top: -40px;'></div>");
  $('.subdiv_' + i).on("click",function () { setImageSlider(i); });
  ```

This does make the code more JQuery, but it does NOT solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery you can do something like this

```
$('#pauseplay').on("click", pauseSlider());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#pauseplay` div is created dynamically, so simple `onclick` shouldn't work in such case, and as soon as you're using jquery, you shoud try smth like

```
$(tabs).on('click', '#pauseplay', function(){
    //do your stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As `#pauseplay` element gets appended dynamically to your DOM, javascript can not recognize it.

You have to use event delegation:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pauseplay', function() {
    // your code ..
});
```